# jQuery slider won't slide to end

Tags: jquery, uislider

I've been messing around with this for some time now and can't figure out the issue...

Can anyone tell me why this slider won't slide fully to the end (right hand side)? I presumed it was because I didn't have MAX set, but then also max doesn't work, because (presumably) I'm using a 3D array for the values?

Any help appreciated, here's the link:
http://statzone.co.uk/slider.php?home=Adelaide&away=Gold%20Coast

Comment: Sorted. Strangely, adding MAX worked. I swear it had issues with that before...

Answer (score 1):

I see this error:
[image: chrome console error]

Firebug console or Chrome console (which is above) is very useful in debugging your javascript

Comment: Thanks Neal...but I still can't see why it can't read that value?

Comment: Try fixing the issue, then you might find the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the code is trying to read outside of "values array" length i.e ui.value is >50. 
e.g. just put these two alerts inside of your slide callback and you will see it.

```
alert(ui.value);
alert(values[ui.value]);
```

I don't have a solution but let me see if I can find one.

**Update 1:**

try setting the min and max values:

```
        value: 23,
        min: 0,
        max:49,
```